# Time series with categorical response variable

Tags: categorical-data, survival, panel-data, time-varying-covariate

I have a question about modelling but I don't even know what kind of model to start looking into.

I have panel data with multiple waves. The response variable I'm interested in is categorical variable (let's call it `status`). This variable has three categories: `willing to be vaccinate`, `unwilling to be vaccinated` and `vaccinated`. The problem is that the `vaccinated` group is getting larger with each wave as people get vaccinated over time.

I'm not sure how to model this type of data structure. Or if that's even possible. Would very much appreciate some guidance towards papers/textbooks/resources that help with modelling these data. Thank you.

Comment: Some type of [multi-state survival model](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/compete.pdf) might be helpful, with `vaccinated` considered an absorbing state, but the details would depend on what you hope to learn from your model.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely look into it! The idea is to understand how external factors (such as e.g., media coverage in between the panel waves) influence the probability to be in one of the categories.